# How to configure MessageFormat for numbers globaly

Tags: java, messageformat

I would like to change the way `MessageFormat` prints out numbers.

```
Integer foo = 99888;
String bar = MessageFormat.format("{0}", foo);
```

Observed value is "99,888".

Desired value is "99888".

What I could do is this:

```
String bar = MessageFormat.format("{0, number,#}", foo);
```

The problem is that I have to change it in a project with more than 10'000 `MessageFormat.format()`. So this is not really the way I would like to do it.

Do you know if there is a way to change the format of numbers given to `MessageFormat.format()` globally?

Comment: static String format;

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you want to say

Comment: keep the format you want to use in your class, and apply it to each number. if you declare it as static, it'll (almost) be (like) global

Comment: Well yeah but then I have to touch every MessageFormat.format() what I would like to avoid.

Comment: @macramser ehm ... why? maybe now the first time, wouldn't be necessary if you had implemented it different before. and it will avoid you having to do it again

Comment: sure only the first time but then I could change to a better formatting lib anyway. and sure it would not be necessary if I had implemented it different before but I have (well not I but other people of my company) so that does not really help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than writing a very strange aspect I don't believe there is a way. That's the price you pay for using a `static` method that you can't modify.

I'd look into doing a bulk change either using your favourite IDE or command line tools e.g. `sed`. If you want to change all occurrences of `{0}` into `{0,number,#}` it should be enough to

```
sed -i -e 's/{0}/{0,number,#}/g' MyClass.java
```

Comment: Ok. Well I don't think I can use sed or something similar. Because of the fact that not all parameters are numbers...

Comment: The numbers are formatted with `NumberFormat.getInstance(locale)` (`MessageFormat` line 1271) which in your case uses `Locale.getDefault()`. There is not much wiggle room here.

Answer (score 2):

Short no.

I would store the pattern `"{0, number,#}"` in a global variable so so have something like a "global" setting.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and I got,

```
bar = "99 888";
```

So I guess it is working.

Comment: Thats not the problem. The problem is that I don't want to change 10'000 lines of code.

Comment: I know, but when you said "Observed value is "99,888"." it seems wrong. Anyway i don't know your project so you'll have to elaborate. Is it one file of 10.000 lines ?  Can't you just do a find/replace in all your project ?

Comment: I think that depence on the location settings. There are like 1'000 classes and not all of the parameters are numbers..